# On "Power-Troubleshooter" event in Task Scheduler not triggering

Tags: task-scheduler, event-viewer, events

I am attempting to run an event via Task Scheduler in order to restart my trackpad driver (code to do so below) every time my system wakes up, as a troubleshooting measure. However, in Task Scheduler, I am having some issues.

If I run the program manually via Task Scheduler it works perfectly and shows up in the event's history. However, giving it the change to try and execute itself after the "Power-Troubleshooter" event is triggered - it just doesn't work. And I need to find out why.

There is no history in the Task Scheduler that shows the event was ever performed, it's just blank. However, I can see in Event Viewer the event 'Power-Troubleshooter' was called. Below are all my configurations:

[image: Task Scheduler - General]
[image: Task Scheduler - Triggers]
[image: Task Scheduler - Action]
[image: Task Scheduler - Settings]

And finally, the actual event that is being triggered in Event Viewer:

[image: Event Viewer - Event]

It's important to note this only works when I run as administrator, for some reason it just does not like it when I select my profile to run the Task on.

Any pointers as to getting this working would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you enabled the administrator account? I use [WinAero](https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836): the [down-load link](https://winaero.com/request.php?1796) is hard to find, but the software is good. Alternatively, [this link](https://winaero.com/blog/enable-or-disable-the-administrator-account-in-windows-10/) shows how to do it manually.

Comment: Yeo! Admin account is active.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here! Turns on, there are actually two listed event 'Source's with BOTH names being "Power-Troubleshooter". Annoying, however, switching to the second one yielded perfect results!

So if anybody else is having this issue, give that a try!

Comment: I can see only one event source called "Power-Troubleshooter" under System. Where is the other?